# Configurar botón

Tags: java, javafx, botón, scenebuilder

Hice un login en JavaFX con Scene Builder y funciona correctamente al hacer clic en el botón, pero también quiero agregarle que al presionar la tecla ENTER ejecute la misma acción sin que el foco este en el botón

```
@FXML
private JFXPasswordField password;

@FXML
private JFXButton acceder;

@FXML
private JFXTextField User;
public static Stage stage;

@FXML
void iniciar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, SQLException {
...
}
```

El ActionEvent lo que hace es que al clickearlo verifica que el usuario y contraseña sean correctos con la base de datos.

Lo que quiero hacer es que ejecute la misma acción al presionar la tecla ENTER y no solo al darle clic al botón.

Comment: Saludos, debes agregar tu codigo para poder darte una mejor  respuesta para esto edita tu pregunta => [edit] <=

Comment: Ya agregué parte del código. Así se entiende mejor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos puedes agregar **setOnKeyPressed** algo asi:

```
JFXPasswordField password;

password.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)  {
          //aqui va lo que deseas hacer
        }
    }
});
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si me funciono, solo tuve que cambiarle un poco porque así como esta me salia que no es compatible.

password.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent event) {
                     if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
                         acceder.fire();
                     }
                }
            });